# How to get date in the url params using nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am having trouble in my api, what is the correct handling or use of date in router and get method?

```
router.get('/school/logs/:app/:remarks/:type/:datefrom/:dateto/:limit/:page', getselectedgroupid);

params = req.params;//get

console.log(params);

let validation_rules = {
    app: 'required',
    module: 'required',
    transtype: 'required',
    datefrom: 'required',
    dateto: 'required',
    limit: 'required',
    page: 'required'
};
.....
```

Api Tester

[image]

[image]

Comment: why not /DD-MM-YYYY/DD-MM-YYYY ,  you can get `datefrom` and `dateto` ?

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, and i tried to uses `/DD-MM-YYYY/DD-MM-YYYY` and i get `no reponse`

Comment: Strange. Did you see log in the console like what does `datefrom` or `dateto` were.

Comment: yes , i will post the picture

Comment: i think you should post the pic/output of values of `datefrom` and `dateto` you get when you run the server. for which you were saying no response